QTableWidget: где изменить ширину столбца?
Есть свой класс на базе QTableWidget. Нужно задавать ширину столбцов в зависимости от ширины текста соответствующего заголовка.
Можно ли это сделать в самом классе?
В конструкторе таблицы или заголовков ещё нет столбцов, поэтому код изменения ширины столбцов туда вставлять бессмысленно. Когда формируются столбцы и текст заголовка?
Когда объект таблицы уже есть, то проблемы изменить ширину столбцов - нет никакой, а можно ли и как это сделать в самом классе?
Спасибо.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. Приглашаем вас ознакомиться со справкой, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Вы можете менять их по сигналу от модели. См. QAbstractItemModel::headerDataChanged

Спасибо, needKVAS. Однако, опыта у меня нет никакого и точного понимания тоже, поэтому ничего не получается.
Сначала ошибочно думал, что setHeaderData - это слот для сигнала QAbstractItemModel::headerDataChanged, стал пытаться переопределять setHeaderData. Потом понял, возможно, тоже ошибочно, что нужно соединить сигнал headerDataChanged со своим слотом, где и менять ширину столбца. Но не могу написать правильный коннект.

Вот код с непонятной ошибкой expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction:
connect(this->horizontalHeader(), &QAbstractItemModel::headerDataChanged, this, &onChanged(Qt::Orientation orientation, int first, int last){...});
Как я понимаю, правильный connect нужно поставить в конструктор моего потомка QTableWidget, т.к. В потомке QHeaderView недоступны columnWidth и setColumnWidth?
Буду благодарен, если кто-то поможет мне поконкретнее).

Такая конструкция сработала: connect(model(), &QAbstractItemModel::headerDataChanged, this, [this](Qt::Orientation orientation, int first, int last){...}, а такая QObject::connect(model(), &QAbstractItemModel::headerDataChanged, this, &onChanged(Qt::Orientation orientation, int first, int last)){...} даёт ошибку в конструкции коннекта.
